# Cannot add or update a child row error

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I keep on receiving this error when I attempt to reply to a post on my forum system:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ('forum'.'posts', CONSTRAINT 'posts_ibfk_2' FOREIGN KEY ('post_by') REFERENCES 'users' ('user_id') 
ON UPDATE CASCADE).
```

I know this question might have been answered but for my DB schema I would like to get more input on where I missed something. Below is my DB schema for users and posts tables:

**users table:**

```
user_id int(8) 
user_name varchar(30)
user_pass varchar(255)   
user_email varchar(255)  
user_date datetime  
user_level int(8)
```

N.B. `user_id` is my `PK`

**posts table:**

```
post_id int(8)           
post_content text                
post_date datetime           
post_topic int(8) 
post_by  int(8)
```

N.B. post_by is the `FK` which references to `user_id` in the users table.

I am pretty sure my schema is not correct or something and your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why cascade on update? When you want to reply to a post, how does your SQL statement look like?

Comment: Here is the SQL statement when replying to a post: $sql = "INSERT INTO posts(post_content, post_date, post_topic, post_by)
VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['reply_content'])."',NOW(), '".mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['id'])."', '".$_SESSION['user_id']."')";

Comment: I can only guess: maybe the session contains a value that's not in users table. try to test it with an hardcoded user id. If no error happens you should check your session value. Since you expect an integer as value you should type cast it. Btw: Isn't post_topic an integer column?

Comment: Thx I will try that out. Because as you said if the session is either null or contains a value that is not in the users table then there will be a problem. I will hardcode it and try to display the $_SESSION[user_id'] on pages to see if it really contains something after login. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks SenseException for your suggestion, it solved my problem. I found out there was a problem with the $_SESSION['user_id']. I tested it to make sure that after login it contains the expected value. Thanks again.